# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unique' BUT I'm not using the 'unique' attribute

Tags: python, django, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm build models in Django 1.8, and I'm using abstract inheritance (which I'm assuming is contributing to the problem). I have abstract models and then I have models which are based on those abstract models. I also have ForeignKey and ManyToMany relations between some models.

Everything looks fine, but when I try to syncdb or 'makemigrations blog' I get an AttributeError which says 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unique'.

I don't know why I'm getting it, and I tried experimenting with different model setups, and I read lots of forum posts, but for now I've hit a wall.

I'll post the traceback and my models below:

MODELS:

indie_db

```
from django.db import models

class URL(models.Model):
    link = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.ForeignKey(URL)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ArtistSingle(Artist):
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    deathdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


class ArtistGroup(Artist):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(ArtistSingle)
    established = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    disbanded = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


class Contributor(models.Model):
    contributing_artist = models.ForeignKey(ArtistSingle, null=True, blank=True)
    alternate_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class ProductionCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.ForeignKey(URL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Work(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    production_company = models.ForeignKey(ProductionCompany, blank=True, null=True)
    self_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
    link = models.ForeignKey(URL)
    styles = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contributors = models.ManyToManyField(Contributor)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class MusicalWork(Work):
    audio_links = models.ManyToManyField(URL)


class WrittenWork(Work):
    excerpt = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


class PerformanceWork(Work):
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class VideoWork(Work):
    length = models.CharField(max_length=16)


class VisualWork(Work):
    images = models.ManyToManyField(URL)
```

blog:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name


class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Blog Entry"
        verbose_name_plural = "Blog Entries"
        ordering = ["-created"]
```

TRACEBACK:

```
[pattmayne@web476 weird_canada]$ python3.4 manage.py makemigrations blog
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 440, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 478, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 1181, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 1258, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1829, in check
    errors = super(ForeignKey, self).check(**kwargs)
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1502, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_unique_target())
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1522, in _check_unique_target
    for rel_field in self.foreign_related_fields)
  File "/home/pattmayne/webapps/limbs_008/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1522, in <genexpr>
    for rel_field in self.foreign_related_fields)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

IF this is caused by my inherited models, what is the exact cause, and how should I change things?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. Did you find a solution? Could you tell us about it?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue is actually with the `Work` models.

You have a ForeignKey to `URL` in the abstract class,

```
link = models.ForeignKey(URL)
```

And you also have keys to `URL` in some of the derived classes, for example MusicalWork:

```
class MusicalWork(Work):
    audio_links = models.ManyToManyField(URL)
```

So MusicalWork has two links to URL. Which would be fine, except Django attempts to create a reverse relationship for URL to your model, usually called `musicalwork_set` for this case, but it has two reverse relationships for the same model!

The answer would be to specify a `related_name` field for any models that derive from it with the same model references.

Therefore:

```
class MusicalWork(Work):
    audio_links = models.ManyToManyField(URL, related_name='musicalwork_audio_set')
```

But there may be other issues as that error message doesn't exactly point to this condition (trust me, Django has a much nicer error message for this particular mistake).

Comment: Why are people downvoting? The issue most certainly was not specifying a `related_name` while having multiple conflicting reverse relationships...

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have a Foreign key to an Abstract Model.

```
creator = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
```

You can change this to `ArtistSingle`

```
creator = models.ForeignKey(ArtistSingle)
```

Ideally it should have thrown a proper error like

> Field defines a relation with model 'Artist', which is either not installed, or is abstract.

But the crash is a [bug with Django 1.8](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25503)